# jQuery autocomplete : move list position?

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, position

I am wondering if it is possible for me to move the dropdown list down 4px?

I have tried several styles in `.ui-autocomplete {}`.

including:

`margin-top: 4px;`
`top: 4px`

but it does not seem to be working?

Comment: could you please be more specific or add some kind of fiddle example?

Comment: im not entirely sure how to be more specific.

The autocomplete list by default sits directly below the input element it is assigned to, I want to move it down 4px

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the [`offset` property](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#option-offset) of the [`position` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-position) is for:

```
$('#myField').autocomplete({
    source: …,
    position: {
        offset: '0 4' // Shift 0px left, 4px down.
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this option is deprecated and removed from jQuery UI. Use the position.my option now instead.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer is **no longer valid** because [the `offset` option was deprecated in jQuery UI v1.9 and completely removed in v1.10](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-offset-option-merged-into-my-and-at):

> The `offset` option has been deprecated and offsets have been merged into the `my` and `at` options. The form for a position is now the named position, optionally followed by a plus or minus and then an offset. In addition, offsets now support percentages (see above). You should replace all uses of the `offset` option with offsets placed inside the `my` and/or `at` options.

You should now write:

```
$(".my-autocomplete-field").autocomplete({
    position: {
        my: "left+0 top+4",
    }
});
```

Comment: This just saved me a lot of time, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
.ui-autocomplete {
     margin-top: 20px !important;
     top: 0px !important;
}
```

Or try

```
.ui-autocomplete {
     margin-top: 20px !important;
     top: auto !important;
}
```

See a demo:

- http://www.jsfiddle.net/xvVKW/1/
- http://www.jsfiddle.net/xvVKW/3/

Comment: it's not always true, when you put a theme to it, it breaks. [Here's one with the default theme](http://www.jsfiddle.net/reigel/xvVKW/2/).

Comment: @Reigel, how did you do that, I couldn't figure it out in jsfiddle. Anyway in that case use `top: auto !important` see http://www.jsfiddle.net/xvVKW/3/

Answer (score 1):

Can't say off the top of my head but it depends what the existing css is...

if the position is absolute then the margin won't effect the box... What you could do is get the resulting div $('.ui-autocomplete') then add 4px to the element's position.

It will either be:

`$('.ui-autocomplete').css('bottom')` or `$('.ui-autocomplete').css('top')`

Get the value of both of these and change them around, see what happens :)